# ACCESS/SQL Combining multiple rows with one column into one row and creating multiple columns

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, pivot

I've looked at quite a few examples and nothing fits quite like I need it to. I have a table that has item numbers in one column and image links in another column. The issue I have is I need to combine rows that have the same item number but need to move the data in the HTML_LINK column to multiple columns called imagelink1, imagelink2, imagelink3. The max amount of imagelink columns I will need is 5. I tried a pivot table which worked to combine the rows, but it creates a column the name of the image link and does not move them to 1 of 5 imagelink columns.

What I have now:

[image: current table]

what I need:

[image: table I need]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. It will likely be useful to include the query you constructed with the `PIVOT()` method as well as the output it was generating so we can work from there. I realize your query wasn't returning the expected results, but you're almost certainly going to want to use the `PIVOT()` method to accomplish this, so it'd be useful to see what you've attempted so we can evaluate why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *crosstab* seems the route to follow, but I couldn't get the subquery to work as suggested by *Parfait* - had to use *DCount*:

```sql
TRANSFORM 
    First(q1.[html_link]) AS html_link
SELECT 
    [item]
FROM 

    (SELECT 
        item, 
        html_link, 
        DCount("*", "mytable", "item = '" & item & "' and html_link <= '" & html_link & "'") AS Index
    FROM 
        mytable) AS q1  

GROUP BY 
    [item] 
PIVOT 
    "ImageLink" & q1.[index];
```

To "clean" the link:

```
Left(Mid([html_link], InStrRev([html_link], "/") + 1), InStr(Mid([html_link], InStrRev([html_link], "/") + 1), ".") - 1) As Link
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. It takes a while but it's a large table so that's to be expected. Is there a way to remove the "http://intranet5/SWA/DrawingImages/" from the beginning of the field and the ".jpg" from the end?

Answer (score 1):

With conditional aggregation:

```
select item,
  max(iif(col = 1, html_link, null)) as imagelink1,
  max(iif(col = 2, html_link, null)) as imagelink2,
  max(iif(col = 3, html_link, null)) as imagelink3,
  max(iif(col = 4, html_link, null)) as imagelink4,
  max(iif(col = 5, html_link, null)) as imagelink5
from (
  select t.*, 
    (select count(*) from tablename where item = t.item and html_link <= t.html_link) as col
  from tablename as t
)
group by item
```

Answer (score 1):

With MS Access' [crosstab query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8) for more dynamic output up to its 255 column limit. However, in order to use subqueries you must specify columns in `PIVOT...IN` clause which requires hard code scripting of all possible columns (i.e.,  max `COUNT`):

```
TRANSFORM MAX(html_link) AS SumOfPrice
SELECT sub.item, COUNT(*) AS [Total]
FROM 
  (select t.item, t.image_link, 
        (select count(*) from mytable
         where item = t.item 
           and html_link <= t.html_link) + 1 as col
   from mytable as t) sub    
GROUP BY sub.item
PIVOT 'imagelink' & col IN ('imagelink1', 'imagelink2', 'imagelink3', ...);
```

Comment: @Gustav, after testing turns out this solution *does* work if you specify all columns in `PIVOT` clause. OP will just need to know in advance the max column or type out all from `imagelink1` to `imagelink253` for Access' limit of columns. Use Excel or code to build these strings in sequence.

Comment: That was not the problem. It was barking because of the field names of the inner query being t.item and the like. No way to resolve it. But I do believe you, I just don't have the time to experiment with it again - it's off-time here.

Comment: Sorry, no luck here. Same error: _There is a syntax error in the TRANSFORM expression_ - which is caused by the underlying table.field name mixup. This is Access 365, perhaps that makes a difference.

Comment: That reveals the true error. Now it asks for the parameter `t.image_link`. That was where I gave up.

Comment: Well I confirm it works in Access 2016 with a reproducible example close to OP's image of data. I even checked via ODBC (outside MSAccess.exe GUI) in Excel ADO, Python, and R! Crosstab with intact subquery comes through. And yes, without listing columns in `PIVOT` I do get parameter error. But thanks for checking and noting possible SQL engine changes to Office 365.

Comment: OK. It seems like we are moving on the edge of SQL parser's capability.