# MS Access - Convert rows values into columns values

Tags: ms-access

I need to convert following Table using MS Access:
[image]

into
[image]
How do I convert it? I am new to ms access 2016.

I have looked into the solution provided in [ACCESS/SQL Combining multiple rows with one column into one row and creating multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60403841/access-sql-combining-multiple-rows-with-one-column-into-one-row-and-creating-mul). But not able to get the result I want in my case.

Comment: If you add an unique counter per combination ob project and asset as a separate field, then you could use a cross tab query.

Comment: You can do it using cursor on MS SQL server `https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e1e3af11-b740-4778-bfd6-7377c69ee0b5/i-need-to-combine-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row?forum=transactsql` but this is not possible with Access.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sql script which works on MS SQL server:

```sql
create table #T (Project varchar(50),Asset varchar(50), OrderNo int)

insert into #T (Project, Asset, OrderNo) values ('ABC','K11',3245) 
insert into #T (Project, Asset, OrderNo) values ('ABC','K11',4564) 
insert into #T (Project, Asset, OrderNo) values ('ABC','K11',5234) 
insert into #T (Project, Asset, OrderNo) values ('XYZ','M33',5346) 
insert into #T (Project, Asset, OrderNo) values ('XYZ','M33',8745) 

declare @Count int,@Cur int
declare @Qry nvarchar(4000)
set @Cur=1
select @Count=max(t.count) from (
select count(OrderNo) count from #T group by Asset)t
set @Qry=''
while @Cur<@Count+1
begin
    set @Qry= @Qry + ',(select t.OrderNo from (select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by OrderNo) ROW_NUMBER, OrderNo from #T where Asset= t1.Asset) t where ROW_NUMBER='+ cast(@Cur as varchar(10)) + ') as OrderNo' + cast(@Cur as varchar(10))
    set @Cur=@Cur+1
end
set @Qry='select distinct t1.Project, t1.Asset  ' + @Qry + ' from #T t1 ORDER BY t1.Project'
print @Qry
exec sp_executesql @Qry
drop table #T
```

and this is the result:

[image]

I do not think you can do it in MS Access.

Comment: He asked for a solution in Microsoft Access, not Microsoft SQL Server. ;-)

Comment: @Unhandled Exception: You are right and I am fully aware of it. I am also coding MS Access and use similar script on SQL server and call it from Access.  Don't you think this would be a solution? This could help him.

Comment: Absolutely, that could be a solution. With SQL Server there should also be more approaches to come to this result. As long as he can/may use a SQL Server at all.

Comment: I would be interested in more solutions of it using SQL. Do you have some?

Comment: Thanks. I would like to see the solution which I can use in MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

Here is pure Access solution using code. It may be done more efficient but you will get the idea now. It creates a temporary table `Transposed` where you find your result. This is MyTable with data

[image]

and this is code for you:

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Function Transpose() As String
    Dim ordersCnt As Integer, sql As String, i As Integer, tempTable As String, f As Variant, myTable As String
    Dim insSql As String, fieldsSql As String, updateSql As String, updateSql2 As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim grp As DAO.Recordset
    tempTable = "Transposed"
    myTable = "MyTable"
    ordersCnt = GetMaxOrders
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    If Not IsNull(DLookup("Name", "MSysObjects", "Name='" & tempTable & "'")) Then
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tempTable
    End If
    fieldsSql = ""
    sql = "CREATE TABLE " & tempTable & " (Project CHAR, Asset CHAR "
    For i = 1 To ordersCnt
        fieldsSql = fieldsSql & ", Order" & i & " INTEGER"
    Next i
    sql = sql & fieldsSql & ")"
    db.Execute (sql)

    insSql = "INSERT INTO " & tempTable & " (Project, Asset) VALUES ("
    Set grp = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT Project, Asset FROM " & myTable & " GROUP BY Project, Asset")
    grp.MoveFirst

    Do While Not grp.EOF
        sql = "'" & grp(0) & "','" & grp(1) & "')"
        db.Execute insSql & sql
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & myTable & " WHERE Project = '" & grp(0) & "' AND Asset = '" & grp(1) & "'")
        updateSql = "UPDATE " & tempTable & " SET "
        updateSql2 = ""
        i = 0
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            i = i + 1
            updateSql2 = updateSql2 & "Order" & i & "= " & rs(3) & ","
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        updateSql = updateSql & Left(updateSql2, Len(updateSql2) - 1) & " WHERE Project = '" & grp(0) & "' AND Asset = '" & grp(1) & "'"
        db.Execute updateSql
        grp.MoveNext
    Loop
End Function

Public Function GetMaxOrders()
   Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
   Dim strSQL As String
   strSQL = "SELECT MAX(CountOfOrderNo) FROM (SELECT Count(OrderNo) AS CountOfOrderNo FROM MyTable GROUP BY Project, Asset)  "
   Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
   GetMaxOrders = rst(0)
   rst.Close
   Set rst = Nothing
End Function
```

and the result:
[image]

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks Vlado for your solution.