# MS-Access Dynamically Convert Variable Row Values into Variable Column Values Using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, dynamic-programming, one-to-many, transpose

**Original code link**: [MS Access - Convert rows values into columns values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60638602/ms-access-convert-rows-values-into-columns-values)

I have a follow up to a question where the answer didn't completely resolve, but got super close. It was asked at the **original code link** above. It's the single page on the net that actually addresses the issue of transposing multiple values in a one-to-many relationship set of columns to a single row for each related value *in a dynamic manner* specifically using VBA. Variations of this question have been asked about a dozen times on this site and literally none of the answers goes as far as Vlado did (the user that answered), which is what's necessary to resolve this problem.

I took what Vlado posted in that link, adjusted it for my needs, did some basic cleanup, worked through all the trouble-shooting and syntax problems (even removed a variable declared that wasn't used: **f As Variant**), and found that it works *almost* all the way. It generates the table with values for the first two columns correctly, iterates the correct number of variable count columns with headers correctly, but fails to populate the values *within* the cells for each of the related "many-values". So close!

In order to get it to that point, I have to comment-out **db.Execute updateSql** portion of the Transpose Function; 3rd to last row from the end. If I don't comment that out, it still generates the table, but it throws a Run-Time Error 3144 (Syntax error in UPDATE statement) and only creates the first row and all the correct columns with correct headers (but still no valid values inside the cells). Below is Vlado's code from the link above, but adjusted for my field name needs, and to set variables at the beginning of each of the two Functions defined. The second Function definitely works correctly.

```
Public Function Transpose()

    Dim DestinationCount As Integer, i As Integer
    Dim sql As String, insSql As String, fieldsSql As String, updateSql As String, updateSql2 As String
    Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset, grp As DAO.Recordset
    Dim tempTable As String, myTable As String
    Dim Var1 As String, Var2 As String, Var3 As String, Var4 As String

    tempTable = "Transposed"        'Value for Table to be created with results
    myTable = "ConvergeCombined"    'Value for Table or Query Source with Rows and Columns to Transpose
    Var1 = "Source"                 'Value for Main Rows
    Var2 = "Thru"                   'Value for Additional Rows
    Var3 = "Destination"            'Value for Columns (Convert from Rows to Columns)
    Var4 = "Dest"                   'Value for Column Name Prefixes

    DestinationCount = GetMaxDestination
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    If Not IsNull(DLookup("Name", "MSysObjects", "Name='" & tempTable & "'")) Then
        DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tempTable
    End If

    fieldsSql = ""
    sql = "CREATE TABLE " & tempTable & " (" & Var1 & " CHAR," & Var2 & " CHAR "
    For i = 1 To DestinationCount
        fieldsSql = fieldsSql & ", " & Var4 & "" & i & " INTEGER"
    Next i
    sql = sql & fieldsSql & ")"
    db.Execute (sql)

    insSql = "INSERT INTO " & tempTable & " (" & Var1 & ", " & Var2 & ") VALUES ("
    Set grp = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT " & Var1 & ", " & Var2 & " FROM " & myTable & " GROUP BY " & Var1 & ", " & Var2 & "")
    grp.MoveFirst

    Do While Not grp.EOF
        sql = "'" & grp(0) & "','" & grp(1) & "')"
        db.Execute insSql & sql
        
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM " & myTable & " WHERE " & Var1 & " = '" & grp(0) & "' AND " & Var2 & " = '" & grp(1) & "'")
        updateSql = "UPDATE " & tempTable & " SET "
        updateSql2 = ""
        i = 0
        rs.MoveFirst

        Do While Not rs.EOF
            i = i + 1
            updateSql2 = updateSql2 & "" & Var3 & "" & i & " = " & rs(2) & ", " ' <------- MADE CHANGE FROM (3) to (2)
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop

        updateSql = updateSql & Left(updateSql2, Len(updateSql2) - 1) & " WHERE " & Var1 & " = '" & grp(0) & "' AND " & Var2 & " = '" & grp(1) & "'"
        db.Execute updateSql ' <-- This is the point of failure
        grp.MoveNext
    Loop
End Function

Public Function GetMaxDestination()

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset, strSQL As String
    myTable = "ConvergeCombined"    'Value for Table or Query Source with Rows and Columns to Transpose
    Var1 = "Source"                 'Value for Main Rows
    Var2 = "Thru"                   'Value for Additional Rows
    Var3 = "Destination"            'Value for Columns (Convert from Rows to Columns)

    strSQL = "SELECT MAX(CountOfDestination) FROM (SELECT Count(" & Var3 & ") AS CountOfDestination FROM " & myTable & " GROUP BY " & Var1 & ", " & Var2 & ")"
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    GetMaxDestination = rst(0)
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
End Function
```

---

Sample Table:

[image: Sample Table]

Sample Data:

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Ampersand (&) character is preferred for text concatenation. Plus (+) will work but if concatenate text to a Null field, Null will return. Right off, I get 'variable not defined' on Var4 and variables in GetMaxDestination. Edit question to show sample table and data.

Comment: I implemented a similar process but instead of code creating a table with customized field names, I just built a permanent table with as many fields as needed (all 255 if that's what it takes) with generic naming like F1, F2, F3, etc. Simplifies code and doesn't require programmatically modifying db structure. Then in report design I use whatever I want in labels instead of the F1, etc names.

Comment: Based on first users input, I exchanged the + values for & values, defined the Val4 variable, and added sample table and data.

Comment: Note for future, sample data as text tables is preferred here over images but I can work with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of a friend I figured it out. It turns out I needed two Functions because the one-to-many relationships go both directions in my case. I explain below what needs to happen in comments for this to work. Essentially I went with the second comment under the question I posed (pre-defining field names in static tables because there is a limited number of fields that any person will need - it can't exceed 256 fields anyway, but it isn't always practical to use more than a dozen or so fields - this way allows for both and at the same time to simplify the code significantly).

This solution actually works - but it's dependent on having tables (or queries in my situation) labeled ConvergeSend and ConvergeReceive. Also, it's important to note that the instances where the Destination is single and the Source is plural, the table or query (ConvergeSend/ConvergeReceive) must have the Destination value as a column TO THE LEFT of the iterated Source columns. This is also true (but reverse naming convention) for the other table/query (the Source column must be TO THE LEFT of the iterated Destination columns).

```
' For this code to work, create a table named "TransposedSend" with 8 columns: Source, Destination1, Destination2,...Destination7; OR however many you need
' Save the table, Edit it, change all field values to Number and remove the 0 as Default Value at the bottom
' Not changing the field values to Number causes the Insert Into function to append trailing spaces for no apparent reason

Public Function TransposeSend()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, grp As DAO.Recordset

    CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM TransposedSend", dbFailOnError

    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO TransposedSend (Source) SELECT DISTINCT Source FROM ConvergeSend GROUP BY Source", dbFailOnError

    Set grp = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT Source FROM ConvergeSend GROUP BY Source")
    grp.MoveFirst

    Do While Not grp.EOF
        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Source, Destination, [Destination App Name] FROM ConvergeSend WHERE Source = " & grp(0))
        i = 0
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            i = i + 1
            CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE TransposedSend SET Destination" & i & " = '" & rs(1) & "', [Destination" & i & " App Name] = '" & rs(2) & "'" & " WHERE Source = " & grp(0)
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        grp.MoveNext
    Loop

End Function


' For this code to work, create a table named "TransposedReceive" with 8 columns: Destination, Source1, Source2,...Source7; OR however many you need
' Save the table, Edit it, change all field values to Number and remove the 0 as Default Value at the bottom
' Not changing the field values to Number causes the Insert Into function to append trailing spaces for no apparent reason

Public Function TransposeReceive()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, grp As DAO.Recordset

    CurrentDb.Execute "DELETE * FROM TransposedReceive", dbFailOnError

    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO TransposedReceive (Destination) SELECT DISTINCT Destination FROM ConvergeReceive GROUP BY Destination", dbFailOnError

    Set grp = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT Destination FROM ConvergeReceive GROUP BY Destination")
    grp.MoveFirst

    Do While Not grp.EOF
        Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Destination, Source, [Source App Name] FROM ConvergeReceive WHERE Destination = " & grp(0))
        i = 0
        rs.MoveFirst
        Do While Not rs.EOF
            i = i + 1
            CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE TransposedReceive SET Source" & i & " = '" & rs(1) & "', [Source" & i & " App Name] = '" & rs(2) & "'" & " WHERE Destination = " & grp(0)
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
        grp.MoveNext
    Loop

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Debug.Print updateSql` before that Execute line and will see improper syntax in SQL statement. Need to trim trailing comma from updateSql2 string. Code is appending a comma and space but only trims 1 character. Either eliminate space from the concatenation or trim 2 characters.
`Left(updateSql2, Len(updateSql2) - 2)`

Concatenation for updateSql2 is using Var3 instead of Var4.

Source field is a number type in ConvergeCombined and this triggers a 'type mismatch' error in SELECT statement to open recordset because of apostrophe delimiters `Var1 & " = '" & grp(0) & "'` - remove them from two SQL statements.

Also, Source value is saved to a text field in Transposed, make it INTEGER instead of CHAR in the CREATE TABLE action.